# Desaturate not working in image styles

Tags: 7, media

I have an image style which has Desaturate and Scale & Crop turned on.

I call it using this:

```
<a href="<?php print image_style_url('gallery_full', $image['uri']); ?>"><img src="<?php print image_style_url('gallery_thumb_grey', $image['uri']); ?>" /></a>
```

It outputs the image resized but doesn't desaturate it. There are no errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which image toolkit are you using, GD or ImageMagick?

Comment: This one is using GD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a crappy answer, but the fix was to switch to using ImageMagick. I still don't know what was wrong with GD.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following discussion on g.d.o to be the most helpful for my particular case of an Ubuntu 8 LTS server which comes with outdated GD libraries.

http://groups.drupal.org/node/35764

Essentially, the only way to get Drupal 7 image desaturation working, without resorting to imagemagick, is to recompile php using the `--with-gd` option.